# Issue with roundings and value comparison in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I try to get the difference between two apparently equal numbers, I get a number different than zero.

```
product_price       min_product_price   price_dif
40,609756097561     40,609756097561         -2,1316282072803E-14
```

I understand this can be a difficult question to answer without all the queries that lead to this, but I'll try to explain,

`product_price` comes straight from the ERP database.

`min_product_price` is obtained with a

```
MIN(ItemSellingPrices.UnitPrice) as min_product_price
```

together with a group by clause. Shouldn't this mean the numbers are the same?

I have no experience with this kind of issues, so I apologize if this is too basic.

Comment: When comparing floating point numbers, you should always use a delta or use a fixed format like @w0lf suggests. You can read up on floating point in [this excellent article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-floats.html) from Rudy Velthuis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a floating point issue.

If you're storing money values in `float` or `real` columns, try using a `decimal`/`numeric` data type instead.

For storing 12 decimal values, you could use `decimal(18, 12)`, for example.

Comment: Actually I'm just using a View. Would that be the same?

Comment: absolutely. You need to change the data type in the table(s) used in the view. Everywhere you store/represent money amounts you should use decimals.

Comment: if you cannot modify the tables (for example they may belong to another application) you can at convert the values to a decimal data type before performing further operations on them

Comment: I guess it would. Finally got it. I set min_product_price as decimal(18,13) and now I have a cleaner result (0,00000..).
Is there any way to turn that it into a "0"? I don't want to open a new topic just for that.

Comment: I think the best way to do that is format the result in the client application/report, using special formatting techniques (for example, C#'s decimal.ToString() method allows you to customize the output format). The alternative in SQL is to convert the result to decimal(18, 0), but that would obviously cause a precision loss which can lead to errors.

Comment: yeah, the idea would be to only turn it into a zero if it equals "0.000000000". 
Since I'm designing an automated CSV export/import system, the method you mentioned is not an option. However, I can deal with it over at the receiving server. I'm reencoding the file using iconv inside a bash file. I can almost certainly find and replace numbers inside it in some similar way. Thank you.

Comment: for completeness' sake:
_sed -i 's/0.0000000000000/0/g' items.txt_
adding that to the bash file does the trick.

Comment: I had to use a different strategy. Using decimal caused what should be "6,5" (float) to turn into "0.00065". I'll leave this as solved, though.

Comment: I don't know why that would happen. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't :( I just ignored it... Right now there's so much more to take care of that I can't dedicate myself to that.